# problems with application.match strings and numbers

Tags: excel, vba, match

I have tried to search and find out why or how to fix this problem.

I have a code that compares values between w1 and w2 and then copy a value from w2 to w1. But it only work when the cell in w1 is a string, not when a number is stored as a string. Hope you understand my problem.

```
Sub UpdateGPL(sheet, cl, ofs)
'sheet = Sheet, cl = column from, ofs = ofset

Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
Dim c As Range, FR As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set w1 = Sheets(sheet)
Set w2 = Sheets("GPL")

w1.Select


For Each c In w1.Range("A2", w1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    FR = Application.Match(c, w2.Columns("C"), 0)
    If IsNumeric(FR) Then c.Offset(, ofs).Value = w2.Range(cl & FR).Value
    
Next c

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try in the next way:

```
For Each c In w1.Range("A2", w1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    FR = Application.Match(c, w2.Columns("C"), 0)
    If IsNumeric(c.Value) Then
        If isError(FR) then FR = Application.Match(CDbl(c.value)
    End If
    If IsNumeric(FR) Then c.Offset(, ofs).Value = w2.Range(cl & FR).Value
    
Next c
```

`Match` function compares identic type of variables. If I correctly understood your question, you should convert it as string when use it (also) for such a case.

Comment: Thanx. This would be a good solution, but i can see that CLng has a limitation and some of the numbers used here is larger than 2,147,483,647

Comment: @Bengt No problem, please use `CDbl` instead of `CLng`. It will work well, even no decimals in place. So, you do not need to convert a number in string, you need to convert a string looking as a number in number (`Double`)...

Comment: Thanx again. But for some reason the c.Value = "2000C" is beeing processed in CDbl, and the gives type mismatch.

Comment: @Bengt Are you joking, or I cannot understand what you try saying? What would you like `CDbl("2000C")` to return?

Comment: No not joking, but not very good in explaning in english :|
Example of values in w1: 35290,MCG-0EL,CABLEEATER2,117402,117408,117404,117407,117409,2000C,FP1,CTS,FCST4
so it works fine with the values before 2000C, but this value is processed in the "if isError FR = ...."

Comment: @Bengt Please, answer my above question: **What would you like CDbl("2000C") to return?** Do you expect it returning **2000**? Do you want using "2000C" as string? What do you try accomplishing, from this point of view? Do you try matching in a strings range? Or in a mixed range? I mean **strings and numbers, too**... You must better describe the the data you try processing...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242324/discussion-between-bengt-and-faneduru).